# Add new column for count of repeated group values

Tags: r, count

I have DF with these two columns: P_ID and PR_ID. There are rows with duplicates for each, some P_IDs have multiple PR_ID and the reverse is also true.
Reproducible example:

```
DF <- data.frame(
    'p_id' = sample(100:300, 100, replace=T),
    'pr_id' = sample(100:300, 100, replace=T)
)
```

I would like a new column pr_count to DF added based on how many pr_id there is for each p_id.

In practice some of the p_ids don't have any pr_id. I want them to have 0 for their pr_count.

Desired output format:

```
p_id  pr_id     pr_count
----  ----      --------
1     2             0
```

Comment: I updated it to include desirable output format. Thanks for the heads up for set.seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Numeric id values**

For this, `ave()` is the workhorse you're looking for. Take a data frame with some p_id's that don't have a pr_id and vice versa :

```
DF <- data.frame(
  'p_id' = sample(100:300, 100, replace=T),
  'pr_id' = sample(100:300, 100, replace=T)
)

DF$pr_id[sample(1:100,10)] <- NA
DF$p_id[sample(1:100,10)] <- NA
```

Use `ave()` to create the vector pr_count

```
DF <- within(DF,{
  pr_count <- ave(pr_id,p_id,
                  FUN = function(x)length(na.omit(x))
                  )
  pr_count[is.na(p_id)] <- 0  
})
```

Note that you have to replace the values in `pr_count` when `p_id` is `NA`. By default, `ave()` will just copy the value of `pr_id` wherever `p_id` is `NA`.

**A General solution**

You have to keep in mind that `ave()` will create a vector that has the same type as the initial `x` argument (in this case, `pr_id`). So if you have character ids, you need to convert to numeric at the end as well:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  'p_id' = sample(letters, 100, replace=T),
  'pr_id' = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace=T),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

DF$pr_id[sample(1:100,10)] <- NA
DF$p_id[sample(1:100,10)] <- NA

DF <- within(DF,{
  pr_count <- ave(pr_id,p_id,
                  FUN = function(x)length(na.omit(x))
                  )
  pr_count[is.na(p_id)] <- 0
  pr_count <- as.numeric(pr_count)

})
```

Which gives again the desired result:

```
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ p_id    : chr  "m" "f" "u" "n" ...
 $ pr_id   : chr  "Y" "W" "R" "M" ...
 $ pr_count: num  2 2 3 2 2 2 2 5 4 2 ...
```

**warning** This behaviour of `ave()` also means that you'll get quite some trouble with factors. Before you use this, make sure that your ids are not stored as factors in your data frame !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'p_id' = sample(100:300, 10, replace=T)
'pr_id' = sample(100:300, 10, replace=T)

DF <- data.frame(p_id, pr_id)
outdf = expand.grid(p_id, pr_id)
outdf$count = ifelse(outdf$Var1==p_id & outdf$Var2==pr_id, 1, 0)
names(outdf)= c("p_id","pr_id","count")

head(outdf)
    p_id pr_id count
1    295   193     1
2    112   193     0
3    283   193     0
4    163   193     0
5    202   193     0
6    135   193     0
```

Comment: That's quite far away from the output requested by the OP. Those are not counts, but a 1/0 indicator in a new dataframe that's a manifold larger than the original.